# addEventListener to simple directive example in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get [this](http://codepen.io/softwareeveryday/pen/beBxmp) very basic directive example to work. From some investigation, 'elem' seems to be an object of **HTMLHeadingElement** (which inherits from Element). Not sure why **elem.addEventListener** would not work. Also, **elem.bind** seems to work however this isn't the [global bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), right?

Also, would be great if someone could touch upon Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 HTML Specification vs Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1 Specification. Happened to come across this for the first time, is this a new Object hierarchy for DOM elements?

Below is the link function of my directive:-

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  // elem will be HTMLHeadingElement object!
  scope.name = 'New Micheal!';
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      elem.css('background-color', 'red');
    })
    /*elem.bind('mouseover', function(e) {
      elem.css('background-color', 'red');
    });
    elem.bind('mouseout', function(e) {
      elem.css('background-color', 'white');
    });*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem` is a jquery (or jqlite) wrapped element. It is not an instance of `HTMLHeadingElement` (although the underlying wrapped instance can be accessed).

To add the click handler, you should be using: `elem.click(function(e) { ... });` instead of `addEventListener`.

---

**EDIT**

The above approach only works if you are using jquery proper (not jqlite). However, in general, you should not be adding handlers through JS. The angular way is to do this in the template.

Something like this:

```
scope.colorHandler = function() {
  elem.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

And in the template:

```
template: '<div ng-click="name = \'colorHandler()\'"><h3>Hello {{name}}!!</h3></div>',
```

In this example, clicking on the `div` will call the color handler.

This is still not canonical angular, since you should be handling css changes through changes in css classes and `ng-class`, but this is getting closer and I hope it illustrates the point.

Comment: Don't think there is a shortcut `click()` unless using jQuery...if it's jQlite have to use `bind('click'`

Comment: Are you using jqlite? In general, though, you should be doing things the angular way and adding the handlers in the templates. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Just curious, when i do an alert(elem) , i see [[object HTMLDivElement]] which made me belive its an HTMLDivElement. Why doesnt alert(elem) give me some hint on the fact that its jqlite object?

Comment: The hint is with the `[[ ]]` A jquery/jqlite wrapped object is wrapped in an array (with extra methods on the prototype). So, what you are seeing is that you have an array of length 1, where the single element is a HTMLDivElement.

Comment: ahh, ok. got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`elem` isn't a DOM element it is a  jQlite object (angular.element) or a jQuery object if jQuery included in page before angular.js

The DOM node is `elem[0]`

Can use the [angular.element API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which is a subset of jQuery methods.

For click listener would be:

```
elem.bind('click',handlerfunc);
```

> This isn't the global bind()

No...it's part of above API and matches jQuery `bind()`

> `bind()` (deprecated, use `on()`) - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 jQlite and javascript options:

**javascript**:

```
elem[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   elem.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

**jQlite**:

```
elem.bind('click', function(e) {
    elem.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```